# Extract Date form DataGridView to DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, datagridview, datetimepicker

Here when  am selecting a row in my `datagridview` I want the date in my database to show up on the `DateTimePicker` I have in my applicaiton.

But I am running into an error which is saying me that`'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'`

Since MySQL takes `'yyyy-MM-dd'` format I changed my `DateTimePicker` format to the same.

I tried extracting the value of the `DataGridView` as a string and found that the format I am getting is `"dd-MM-yyyy hh:MM:ss t"`

What can I do to resolve it?

```
private void dtv_dis1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        txt_id.Text = dtv_dis1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        txt_amt.Text = dtv_dis1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        txt_remarks.Text = dtv_dis1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        //Error with date
        String date = dtv_dis1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        dtp_date.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        //textBox1.Text = dtv_dis1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

        tot = dtv_dis1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        mop = dtv_dis1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        cur = dtv_dis1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        if (tot == "Domestic")
        {
            rb_dom.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            rb_in.Checked = true;
        }
        if (mop == "Cash")
        {
            rb_csh.Checked = true;
        }
        else if (mop == "Credit Card")
        {
            rb_cc.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            rb_nb.Checked = true;
        }
        if (cur == "Doller")
        {
            rb_doller.Checked = true;
        }
        else if (cur == "Euro")
        {
            rb_euro.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            rb_Rupees.Checked = true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: How is the `DateTime` value getting into the grid in the first place? If the grid uses a data source like a `DataTable`, then, I would assume the date value column is of a type `DateTime`… if not…, it should be. What is the data type of the date column in the grid?

Comment: Its ```DATE``` in the date column in the grid @JohnG

Answer (score 0):

If the grids data source is a `DataTable` and the “Date” column’s type is a type of `DateTime`, then, it should be unnecessary to “parse” the date…

Simply grab the "data" row from the data source, then grab the `DateTime` value directly from the cell… something like…

```
if (dtv_dis1.CurrentRow != null) {
    DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)dtv_dis1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
    dtp_date.Value = (DateTime)drv["Date"];
}
```

As commented, if the column type is a `string` type… then I suggest you change it to a type of `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

A recommendation, load database data into a **DataTable** or **List<T>** then using a BindingSource assign the DataTable or List<T>.

Add a `DataBinding` to the DataTimePicker, set `Format` property to Custom, set `CustomFormat` to yyyy-MM-dd.

If using a List<T> and want to reflect changes in the DataGridView, implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in the class representing `T`.

There is quirk with a List<T> and BindingSource to refect changes to the source so subscribe to `ValueChanged` event of the DateTimePicker and set the DateTime column value.

The screenshot below has the Date shown in the DataGridView with a custom DataGridView column where the birth date is synchronous with the DateTimePicker.

[image]

In general, typically one does not want to access data in a DataGridView through cells but instead as indicated above through the DataSource in the above a BindingSource.

To get at the current row in the DataGridView via a BindingSource, first assert the .Current property is not null, if not null case Current to the type eg. DataRow for a DataTable, a class type for a list.

In the following the DataSource is a List using Person1 class to get the current row information from a DataGridView shown above.

```
private void CurrentPersonButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (_bindingSource is null || _bindingSource.Current is null) return;

    var current = (Person1)_bindingSource.Current;

    MessageBox.Show(
        $"{current.FirstName} {current.LastName}\n" + 
        $"{current.BirthDate.Value:yyyy-MM-dd}");
}
```

[image]